# Creating a copy of a file, that gets automatically updated

Tags: files, symlink

I'm using Fedora 26. I want a script to run at startup, but also have this script in my scripts folder. How can I make it so the `/etc/init.d/foo` gets updated when I edit `~/scripts/bar`? I was thinking about a symbolic link, but i don't really know how to get it going

Comment: `ln -s /etc/init.d/foo ~/scripts/bar`—and please *don't* do it the other way around in production code.  Init scripts should be owned by root.

Comment: This setup is a little bit odd, actually.  I wonder what you use your "scripts" directory for?  Not as part of your PATH, surely?  (I wouldn't want an init script in my path lookup.)

Comment: I just have a couple of scripts I sometimes use. Some of them I would like to run at startup.

Comment: To avoid all that, isn't there any like `crontab` file/command? I just switched from Debian

Comment: Yes.  `crontab`, not `contrab`.  The "tab" is for "table."  And "cron" comes from "chronological" and relates to time.

Comment: I found out how to make them work monthly. In Debian on reboot it was `@reboot`. Is there smth like this in Fedora?

Comment: Yes.  You should read the man page.  `man 5 crontab`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symlinks are pretty straight forward, but you need to understand the changes are bi-directional, a change to the content of the symlink affects the original file and vice versa. That's because the symlink is really just a pointer to the original file and when you open a symlink your application silently opens the original instead.

If that's what you want, just do (from the terminal):

`ln -s /PATH/TO/TARGET/FILE /PATH/TO/NEW/SYMLINK`

You don't need a script to update the symlink then. You can also create relative symlinks by making the path to the target file a relative path (as viewed from where the symlink will be kept). Like so:

```
cd /home/myuser/folder1/folder2
ln -s ../file-in-folder1 symlink-in-folder2
```

but if you then move your symlink to another directory it will break it's reference to the original file.

You can view where symlinks link to with the long output from ls:

`ls -l /PATH/TO/SYMLINK` or `ls -l /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/WITH/SYMLINKS/IN/IT`

You can also make symlinks to directories themselves. Same rules apply. Only difference from normal directories is that you don't have to recurse them with the `-r` flag when removing them with `rm`. Cause they aren't really a directory... they are a file that points to a directory.

Comment: Makes sense. Sorry for picking it so late. Had a lot on my head